# Python Tkinter as a systemctl service

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to run a Python Tkinter module on Linux ubuntu as a systemctl service
the goal is to create some kind of listener service, and when the logic reaches
the service will activate a python program that contain a tkinter window

so far I managed to make it work, but as soon as the goal reaches
(in this example, it will be storage monitor - whenever reaches 90% usage - it activates a python program)
the service then crashes.

i've checked and read around, that it can be problematic to run a graphical methods from a systemd services.
but perhaps some one here can help me out...

this is the service creating:

```
[Unit]
Description=Storage Monitor Service
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=${current_user}
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env python3 ${destination_path}main.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

the python code is too long to post here, but running the program works outside the service.

anyway, running 'systemctl status service.service'
showing the service active(running)
everything is fine, until...

I'm running - 'fallocate -l xxG /path/file.txt' to test the storage limit goal reach
and then the service crashes with these errors:

```
env[950842]: Traceback (most recent call last):
env[950842]:   File "/home/user/bin/main.py", line 72, in <module>
env[950842]:     monitor_storage(threshold_percentage=90, check_interval=5)
env[950842]:   File "/home/user/bin/main.py", line 57, in monitor_storage
env[950842]:     center_messagebox(tk.Tk(), "Error", f"An error occurred: {e}")
env[950842]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
env[950842]:     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
env[950842]: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
systemd[1]: storage_monitor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: storage_monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I understand that it failing due to the Environment=DISPLAY=:0
but that is the only way I could make the service active(running) in the first place.
and the python program working outside of the service, as individual code.
but as soon as its running over systemd service, its crashing.

any idea is appreciated since I can not figure it out yet.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda figured it out.
for some reason the display x server was not ":0"
so I just modified in the shell script that creates the service, the following

```
Environment=DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

since when I did `echo $DISPLAY` it showed :100.
so instead of setting it, I made it more dynamic

although I'm having other issues and misunderstandings now.
for example, when I'm running the program as python code
the notification window pops up and opens 'baobab' and everything works fine.
but when same is done via the service, the notification window stuck.

I guess i'll do more testing and will try to figure out